# Make a activity screen which shows up only once

Tags: java, android

I want to make a activity in an app which shows up only when the user installs the app and never again. How can I do that?

Comment: I did the first step inside the onCreate() of the main activity                  and then added         if( preferences.getBoolean("screen_show",false)) {
            editor.putBoolean("screen_show", true);
            //App has run for the first time;
            Intent IntentFirstRunAct = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstRunActivity.class);
            startActivity(IntentFirstRunAct);
        }        It is not changing the activity.   Please help!!!

Comment: you need to mention all this in your post so that others can help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.store value in sharedPrefernces.

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("SoldiPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("screen_show", false);
editor.commit();
```

2. get value from sharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("SoldiPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.getBoolean("screen_show", false);
```

3.It is false first time always

```
if( ! preferences.getBoolean("screen_show", false)){
    // if show screen 
    Intent showscreenIntent=new(this,ShowScreen_Intent.class);
    startActivity(showscreenIntent);
} else {
    //
}
```

4.after showing screen first time set true in shared prefernece like this.

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("SoldiPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("screen_show", true);
editor.commit();
```

Now whenever step 3 execute else condition run and Activity will never show again.

hope it helps !!!

Comment: I did the first step inside the onCreate() of the main activity                  and then added         if( preferences.getBoolean("screen_show",false)) {
            editor.putBoolean("screen_show", true);
            //App has run for the first time;
            Intent IntentFirstRunAct = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstRunActivity.class);
            startActivity(IntentFirstRunAct);
        }        It is not changing the activity.   Please help!!!

Comment: Thanks for answering sir that really helped..!! and it solved my issue, thought it was a very basic one.

Comment: Glad it helps you. happy coding  :)

Answer (score 0):

My issue solved by trying out this

```
boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("Preference", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("isfirstrun",true);

    if(isFirstRun){
        getSharedPreferences("Preference", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("isfirstrun",false).commit();
        Intent IntentFirstRunAct = new Intent(MainActivity.this,FirstRunActivity.class);
        startActivity(IntentFirstRunAct);
    }
```